# Is it possible to capture DDL events against a specific set of tables with PostgreSQL's event triggers?

Tags: postgresql, event-triggers

Can I restrict an event trigger to only capture events when DDL is performed against a specific set of tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid capturing the event, as the current [`CREATE EVENT TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html) statement only supports filtering by [command tag](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-matrix.html).

Once you're in the trigger function, you have access to [a bit more information](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-event-triggers.html), so you could put something like this at the top:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
    WHERE object_identity NOT IN ('myschema.mytable')
  )
THEN
  RETURN;
END IF;
```